# How to properly load my xib file with Auto Layout in a container in my storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a `xib` file where the owner is `MyClass`, a subclass of `UIView`. Then there is a container in my storyboard that is of `MyClass` type and will then contain my `xib` file.

In my `xib` file I laid down all the necessary constraints for auto layout.

In `MyClass`, I load the `xib` file like this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addSubview(NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyXibFile", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView)
}
```

The problem with this way of loading the `xib` file is that I end up having an extra `UIView` between my container in the storyboard and the `xib`, so I have to lay out again (programmatically...) all the constraints for this extra `UIView`. It is not a big deal to create those constraints but I guess there is a better way or I am doing something wrong somewhere.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you want create custom UIView using a xib which will be reusable for you and you want to add on you view controller there is a better tutorial on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP7YvdlnHfA
please watch the video .

Comment: Yes I saw the video a while ago but it does it the way I do it as well. I thought there would be another way than adding the loaded xib as a subview of my view container, like my view container becomes straight my xib file. Thanks anyway.